# how use multiple join in linq?

Tags: linq, join, lambda, linq-to-entities, sum

```
 var abc1 = from dlist in db.DebtorTransactions.ToList()
                       join war in db.Warranties on dlist.ProductID equals war.Id
                       join ag in db.Agents on war.fldAgentID equals ag.pkfAgentID
                       join sr in db.SalesReps on war.fldSrId equals sr.pkfSrID
                       where dlist.TransTypeID == 1
                       select new
                       {
                          dlist.Amount,
                           dlist.TransTypeID,
                           name = ag.Name,
                           ag.pkfAgentID,
                           sr.pkfSrID,
                           salesnam = sr.Name
                       } into objabc
                       group objabc by new
                       {
                           objabc.TransTypeID,
                           objabc.name,
                           objabc.salesnam,
                           objabc.Amount
                       };
            var amt1 = abc1.Sum(x => x.Key.Amount);


            var abc2 = from dlist in db.DebtorTransactions.ToList()
                       join cjt in db.CarJackaTrackas on dlist.ProductID equals cjt.pkfCjtID
                       join ag in db.Agents on cjt.AgentID equals ag.pkfAgentID
                       join sr in db.SalesReps on cjt.SalesRepId equals sr.pkfSrID
                       where dlist.TransTypeID == 0
                       select new
                       {
                           dlist.Amount,
                           dlist.TransTypeID,
                           name = ag.Name,
                           ag.pkfAgentID,
                           sr.pkfSrID,
                    enter code here`       salesnam = sr.Name
                       } into objabc
                       group objabc by new
                       {
                           objabc.TransTypeID,
                           objabc.name,
                           objabc.salesnam,
                           objabc.Amount
                       };
            var amt2 = abc1.Sum(x => x.Key.Amount);
            //var result1=
            return View();
```

i am new to linq, this query is working but i need to get the sum of Amount where dlist.TransTypeID == 0 and where dlist.TransTypeID == 1 by just single query. may anybody help me? thanks in advance

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you're asking. Are you trying to get the sum of `dlist.Amount` for records where `dlist.TransTypeID == 0` OR `== 1`. Or do you want two amount results, one where `TransTypeID == 0` and another where `TransTypeId == 1`?

Comment: yes @Ocelot20 i want two results where TransTypeID == 0 TransTypeId == 1 with just one query. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a trimmed down example of how you can do it. You can add the joins if they are necessary, but I'm not clear on why you need some of the extra join values.

```
var transTypeAmountSums = (from dlist in db.DebtorTransactions
                           group dlist by dlist.TransTypeId into g
                           where g.Key == 0 || g.Key == 1
                           select new
                           {
                               TransTypeId = g.Key,
                               AmountSum = g.Sum(d => d.Amount)
                           }).ToDictionary(k => k.TransTypeId, v => v.AmountSum);

int transTypeZeroSum = transTypeAmountSums[0];
int transTypeOneSum = transTypeAmountSums[1];
```

A couple of things to note:

1. I removed `ToList()`. Unless you want to bring ALL DebtorTransactions into memory then run a Linq operation on those results, you'll want to leave that out and let SQL take care of the aggregation (it's much better at it than C#).
2. I grouped by `dlist.TransTypeId` only. You can still group by more fields if you need that, but it was unclear in the example why they were needed so I just made a simplified example.